# i want to set my image with full width. but how to fit it?

Tags: html, css

i want to cover this image at full width size but it's not fitting properly, please help how to fit it properly here is an image.

http://postimg.org/image/u53oikyc5/

and here is my source code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Select your college from list.
    </title>
    <style>
        #img{
            width: 950px;
            height: 350px;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
    <div id="img">
        <img id="img" src="images/college_name.jpg" alt="Select_your_college"/>
    </div>
    </body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Use 'height:100%' and 'width:100%'.... This will cause some distortion

Answer (score 0):

Give `min-width: 100%` to `<img />`.

Answer (score 0):

first of all use `.img img{width:100%}` then

try using **css reset**:

The goal of a reset stylesheet is to reduce browser inconsistencies in things like default line heights, margins and font sizes of headings, and so on. The general reasoning behind this was discussed in a May 2007 post, if you're interested. Reset styles quite often appear in CSS frameworks, and the original "meyerweb reset" found its way into Blueprint, among others.

The reset styles given here are intentionally very generic. There isn't any default color or background set for the body element, for example. I don't particularly recommend that you just use this in its unaltered state in your own projects. It should be tweaked, edited, extended, and otherwise tuned to match your specific reset baseline. Fill in your preferred colors for the page, links, and so on.

In other words, this is a starting point, not a self-contained black box of no-touchiness.
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 0):

I consider myself to give this answer, i used this:

```
#img{
            width: 102%;
            z-index: 0;
            height: 350px;
            overflow: hidden;
            padding: 0px;
            margin-top: -9px;
            margin-left: -8px;
            margin-right: 9px;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset `margin` and `padding` of your `html` and `body` to zero to get your image touched to the browser's initials.

**CSS**:

```
body,html{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

img.fullwidth{
min-width:100%;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Full width Image</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img class="fullwidth" src="url/to/your/image.jpg"/>
    </body>
</html>
```